# Trigger spring batch job automatically

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is there any option to run Spring Batch job automatically without scheduling or trigger it from other source?

We can run spring batch job by scheduling expression or by main method (As mentioned below).

```
public static void  runBatch() {
    JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) getApplicationContext().getBean("jobLauncher");

    Job job = get Job details here;
    JobParametersBuilder jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder();
    // Setting Job Parameter and run job using below
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters.toJobParameters());      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    runBatch();
}
```

Means we need to call main method manually or by some other scheduler so that it will trigger. Without this main method or scheduler can we call this batch process automatically? Or Is there any better options?

> 1. Spring batch should trigger automatically without triggering from any entry point its like daemon thread.
> 2. Suppose once batch is processing data using spring batch. How can automatically trigger spring batch job after completion of running
>      job?

Comment: This is independent from Spring Batch. To run some code, you either need to schedule it (at some point in time or at a regular interval) using a scheduler, or trigger it based on some event. I don't see any other option. So "run Spring Batch job automatically without scheduling or trigger it from other source" is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Many options exist to trigger the batch:

1. To call a batch from another scheduler, issue run parameters there and trigger the Job.
2. If it has to be triggered automatically, say may be on certain interval, use `fixedDelay` scheduling
3. To trigger manually, you can go for MBean approach where it can be triggered from JConsole.
4. Or have an endpoint to call `runBatch`.